# Dynamic HTML form and saving into multiple records in DB

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am writing a small app using codeigniter to track payments and payments dates. I have a form where we input details about the customer, and among those fields, we enter how many instalments will be used for the customer to pay his entire premium.

The next page takes this number, and generates the same number of fields. For example instalment_1, date_1; instalment_2, date_2.

```
<?php for($i=1; $i<=$instalments; $i++):?>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div><label>Instalment <?php echo $i;?></label></div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="instalment_<?php echo $i;?>" name="instalment_<?php echo $i;?>">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row form-group">
    <div><label>Premium Date <?php echo $i;?></label></div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="date_<?php echo $i;?>" name="date_<?php echo $i;?>" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea is now to loop through this form, and save each set of instalment and date into 1 record in the database.
i was able to do it if i have only one type of fields (eg instalments). but when i added the date, it is saving, but each record gets created twice.

```
$post = $this->input->post();   
foreach($post as $key=>$value){
            //check for the word instalment
            if(strpos($key, "instalment") == 0){
                //get the instalment number from the name of the field
                $inst_number = substr($key, -1);
                //Use $category_id and $value in this loop to build update statement
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$inst_number');</script>";
                //$arr = "inst_".$inst_number;
                //reform the name of the field to get the values from it
                $instalment_var = "instalment_".$inst_number;
                $date_var = "date_".$inst_number;
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$instalment_var');</script>";
                $amount = $this->input->post($instalment_var);
                $date = $this->input->post($date_var);
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$amount');</script>";
                $arr = array(
                    'payment_amount' => $amount,
                    'payment_date' => $date,
                    'policy_name' => $policy_id,
                );
                if(!$this->Policy_model->save_payment_details($arr)){
                    redirect('ships/index');
                }
            }
        }
```

How can i do it so that i don't have every record saved twice? and if i add another field, it will get saved 3 times.

i though about naming the div, and working on this, but i didnt get any result.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.This will resolve your issue.

View:

```
<form action="action.php" method="POST">
<?php for($i=1; $i<=$instalments; $i++){?>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div><label>Instalment <?php echo $i;?></label></div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="instalment[]" name="instalment[]">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row form-group">
    <div><label>Premium Date <?php echo $i;?></label></div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="date_<?php echo $i;?>" name="date[]" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

In your controller:

```
$post = $this->input->post();
   $i=0;
   foreach($post as $key=>$value){
       $arr = array(
                    'payment_amount' =>$post['instalment'][$i],
                    'payment_date' => $post['date'][$i],
                    'policy_name' => 1,
                );
        $i++;
   }exit;
```

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try when i get back home, and will let you know.

Comment: sounds good. You can try it.you can save the data as each record

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work mostly. it is saving one less record than i have, but this shouldn't be an issue. will figure it out. Thanks a lot :)